# Advantage .NET Data Provider Version 8.1

Tags: .net, advantage-database-server

I am developing a C# program to connect to Advantage Database Server version 8.1. I downloaded Advantage .NET Data Provider version 8.1 from Advantage Developer Zone but that version of Advantage .NET Data Provider is missing Advantage Client Engine API Class inside the Advantage.Data.Provider.dll file. Where can I get the Advantage Client Engine API for C# environment?

Comment: Have you tried http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20  Also, are you intending to use Advantage SERVER or Advantage LOCAL Database...  Or was this the link you were referring to.

Comment: @DRapp The Advantage .NET Data Provider I downloaded is from the same link that you mentioned. For Version 9 and above, the Advantage Client Engine API is available inside the Advantage.Data.Provider.dll but it is missing from version 8.1. I can't use version 9 and above because the Advantage Database Server that my employer is using is version 8.1. Thanks.

Comment: There is no *Advantage Client Engine API for C# environment*. That's what the .NET Data Provider supplies (the .NET/C# API). The Advantage Client Engine is a series of DLLs written in C and supplied as DLLs (ace32.dll, adsloc32.dll, axcws32.dll) that are loaded and used internally by the .NET Data Provider. They're automatically installed when you install the .NET Data Provider.